# how to connect to local oracle database 19c using sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

i have install oracle 19c in my PC, but when i want to connect using SQL Plus i cannot login. i got error like this
the error is like my password wrong or cannot open.

[image: error when try using Default password]
when i install the installer not require password. when i try to use default password as password i got error. so how to fix my problem here ?? i have try search in internet how to fix it but still got error

i use Windows 10 for this Oracle19c

Answer (score 1):

There's no *default password* any more; was until (I think) 10g.

If you're logged on to Windows 10 as user who installed Oracle software, then - at the operating system command prompt - run

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

`/` means that Oracle trusts your operating system account as it is recognized as the "owner" of installed Oracle software and should let you in. Once you're logged into the database, change any password you want for any user you want, e.g.

```
alter user sys identified by some_new_password;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TNS: Protocol adapter error` usually means you don't have your envirnoment set correctly

Try defining the `ORACLE_SID` variable with your database name and then connect again `/as sysdba`

Also, i'd advise you to set your `ORACLE_HOME` too, if it's not already

```
set ORACLE_HOME=<YourOracleHomePAth>
set ORACLE_SID=<YourDBName>
```

There's no default password, the installer should've asked you to set a password for your `SYS` and `SYSTEM` users - if you don't remember them, you can always change them, once connected to the Database, by issuing the command

```
alter user sys identified by <NewPassword>;
alter user system identified by <NewPassword>;
```